# vim/gvim difference between close and hide

Tags: vim

I'm kind of new to VIM, I'd like to know the difference between the `:close` window command and the `:hide` window command. I've read the docs but they both seem to do the about same...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `:clo[se][!]`

**Can**:

- fail when there is only one window on the screen.
- `:set hidden`.
- use [!] to exit the current session without saving it (i.e. `:clo[se]!`).

**Can't**

- execute a side command.

---

## `:hid[e]`

**Can't**

- fail when there is only one window on the screen.
- `:set hidden` (irrelevant).
- use [!] to exit the curent session without saving it.

**Can:**

- execute a side command (i.e. `:hid[e] {cmd}`).

This side command executes `{cmd}` with `:set hidden`. After execution of `{cmd}`, the previous value of `:set hidden` is restored. For example, `:hide edit example` will edit `example` and hide the current buffer if it has any changes.

---

(Referenced from `:help close` and `:help hide` from `$vim`)